# Problem with installing python-gi-cairo on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, installation, cairo

When I'm running this code in Bash:

`sudo apt-get install -y python-gi-cairo`

I get this message från Bash:

> "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation, or if you are using an unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incomming.
> The following information may help to solve the situation:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> python-gi-cairo : Depends: python-gi (= 3.36.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

I'm using a Raspberry pi3

What I have done before I tried to install python-gi-cairo:

- Downloaded and installed missing keys for APT.
- Updated APT

Grateful for help /Felix

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please replace image with its text.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the default Python is 2.7.
No worries I had the same issue.

But Fixed it with python3.

Try:

```
sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I tried, but got this output:  
 
 Reading package lists... Done 
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
        E: Unable to locate package python3-gi-cario